# Sum involving inverse of binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics

I am interested in showing the following or finding a counterexample to the following if the equation does not hold. Any ideas?

> Suppose $n, k$ are both positive integers. Show or disprove the following:
> $$\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{nk - k}{nk - 1 \choose i} = \frac{nk}{nk - 1}$$

Thanks!

(this arises in figuring out the expectation in coupon collection without replacement)

Comment: Have you tried any examples with $k \ne 2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $k = 1$, this is not true, the left side of this equality is $\frac{n-1}{n-1} = 1$ and the right side is $\frac{n}{n-1}$ which are not equal. Do you want to know if it is true for every $n,k$ possible or for a fixed $n$ or for a fixed $k$ ?